# Count number of records in a doctrine collection

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm trying to display the number of records returned by a doctrine collection

```
    $t_liste_cra = Doctrine::getTable('Cra')->findByDateAndIdUser($date->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'), $_SESSION['front']['user']);

        echo ($t_liste_cra->count());
```

This does not work unfortunately. I'm using doctrine 1.4

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try:

```
$t_liste_cra->rowCount();
```

When you have doubts, look at the Doctrine's source code (the best manual ever)